# Amazon Login with Webrequest

Tags: c#, authentication, httpwebrequest

I'm in the process of making a personal program for myself (I've made a thread on it before) in which I make an Amazon recent items checker where I can just pull all my purchases and populate them in a listview on the form.

up to this point I've been using a webbrowser, but that method is taking way to long. So I figured I would have a go with webrequests and try it that way, I've been trying and trying but I can't replicate the POST request to login to http://Amazon.com.

Here's my code:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin?_encoding=UTF8&openid.assoc_handle=usflex&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.ns.pape=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fpape%2F1.0&openid.pape.max_auth_age=0&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fgp%2Fyourstore%2Fhome%3Fie%3DUTF8%26ref_%3Dgno_signin");

    var postData = "All this data is so long, there's no point of posting it";
    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;

    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Source.html", responseString);
```

As you can see I'm outputting the source to check if it logs in, but it always just gives me the login page right back, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="appActionToken" value="UAb18OpXSFRCv7cVFj2BhFSMSrjOoj3D">` For a start you will need to make a get request to retreive this token, plus save any cookies and send them with the post request. There is probably a number of other security measures as well - websites dont like you doing this, so they make it hard

Comment: Ye, I know that for sure; alright so I'll start by trying to grab that token. Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Curl - Cookies problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522149/php-curl-cookies-problem) the highest voted answer used to work in 2011 but not anymore. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888549/programatically-login-to-amazon-with-c-sharp - where it's pointed out what the javascript on amzon's sign-in pages do.